# how can it do other work except "async_wait" in one single thread using boost.asio.deadline_timer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I rewrite a boost.asio example "Timer.3 - Binding arguments to a handler". I think "worker" can work forever and "print" can be called each second. But "print" only is called once. It is very diffcult for me to think why.

If this can't work,how can I do other things except "async_wait" in one single thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int num = 0;
void worker(){
    while(1){
        ++num;
    }
}
void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/,
    boost::asio::deadline_timer* t, int* count)
{
    std::cout << *count << "\n";
    ++(*count);

    t->expires_at(t->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    t->async_wait(boost::bind(
        print, boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, count
    ));
    if(*count == 1){
        worker();
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;

    int count = 0;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    t.async_wait(boost::bind(print,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t, &count
    ));
    io.run();

    std::cout << "Final count is " << count << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop

```
void worker() {
    while(1) {
        ++num;
    }
}
```

so control never returns the first time `print()` is invoked.

Comment: yes,this is the function i want. Can it be interrupted by deadline_timer? I think it can act like "setitimer".thanks.

Comment: You can interrupt an outstanding deadline timer with [cancel](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html).